# How can I save my log file in Python when the process is killed

Tags: python, logging, io

I am learning the `logging` module in Python.

However, if I log like this

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='mylog.log',format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

while 1:
    logging.debug("something")
    time.sleep(1)
```

and interrupt the process with control-C event(or the process is killed), nothing I can got from the log file.

Can I save the most logs whatever happens?

————

### EDIT

the question seem become more complex:

I have imported scipy, numpy, pyaudio in my script, and I got:

> forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event

instead of `KeyboardInterrupt`

I have read this question: [Ctrl-C crashes Python after importing scipy.stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457786/ctrl-c-crashes-python-after-importing-scipy-stats)

and add these line to my script:

```
import _thread
import win32api
def handler(dwCtrlType, hook_sigint=_thread.interrupt_main):
    if dwCtrlType == 0: # CTRL_C_EVENT
        hook_sigint()
        return 1 # don't chain to the next handler
    return 0 # chain to the next handler
```

then:

```
try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("exit manually")
    exit()
```

Now, the script stops without any info if I use ctrl+C. `print("exit manually")` does not appear. Of course, no logs.

### Solved

A stupid mistake!
I run the script when working directory is `System32` and want to find log in the script's path.

After I change the route like this, all is well.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+os.sep+'mylog.log',format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Without knowing how you have configured the logger, it's hard to tell whether you should get any output at all? As BrianO indicates, `logging.debug` is by default not logged. And you mention a log file, but the default logging output is `sys.stderr`, not a file.

Comment: There is also quite a difference between interrupting a process using control-C and a processing being killed. I don't know about Windows (which you appear to be using), but on e.g. *nix, there is a variety of ways to kill a process (that is, a variety of signals can be send to a process that may stop that process). You'll need to be more clear whether you're only talking about control-C (which can be intercepted using `except KeyboardInterrupt`) or other interrupts.

Comment: @Evert, I found my stupid mistake. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log using `logging.debug`, `logging.info`, ..., `logging.critical`, you're using the *root* logger. I assume you're not doing anything to configure logging that you haven't shown, so you're running with the out-of-the-box, default configuration. (This is set up for you by the first call to `logging.debug`, which calls `logging.basicConfig()`).

The default logging level of the root logger is `logging.WARNING` (as mentioned in e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). Thus, nothing you log with `logging.debug` or `logging.info` will appear :) If you change `logging.debug` to `logging.warning` (or `.error` or `.critical`), you *will* see logging output.

For your code to work as is, set the logging level of the root logger to `logging.DEBUG` before the loop:

```
import logging
import time

# logging.getLogger() returns the root logger
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

while 1:
    logging.debug("something")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> event use a `try`-`except` to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: @PaleNeutron You're defining the `handler` function but what about the previous `ctypes` calls and all that stuff? Also, why are you using `_thread` instead of `thread`? You can't do anything if your process is killed.