# Ctrl-C exits out of Cython interpreter on Windows

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cython

The typical behavior for the Python interpreter is to stop the currently running command when you press Ctrl-C. For some reason, my interpreter (Cython 2.7.10, Windows 10) completely exits python when I press Ctrl-C instead (similar to what Ctrl-Break does). How can I fix this to get back to the default behavior?

Comment: wrap your code in a `try:` / `except SystemExit:`?

Comment: You might want to edit your title to say Cython interpreter, and not Python. If that's what you're using.

Comment: @Julius Wouldn't you want `try:` / `except KeyboardInterrupt:` ?

Comment: Seems like a bug. For me, on Python 2.7.12 (Win10), Ctrl-C is caught and "KeyboardInterrupt" is printed. On 3.5.2 (Win10), the interpreter just exits.

Comment: What's the interpreter's current `SIGINT` handler, i.e. `signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)`?

Comment: Are you using Cython to create an extension module or an executable? If you create a complete, minimal example, I'll try to reproduce and diagnose the problem.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457786/ctrl-c-crashes-python-after-importing-scipy-stats) solved this problem for me so it was probably related