# Capturing Python KeyboardInterrupt in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-events, try-except, keyboardinterrupt

I want to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in my Python code in Visual Studio Code. In both integrated and external consoles, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> results in **"forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to control-C event"** and my try-except statement doesn't catch the interrupt. The code is in this form:

```
def main():
    try:
        somecode
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        somecode
```

Comment: I think it isn't a vscode problem. I tested with python 2.7 and 3.5  and it works. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112343/how-do-i-capture-sigint-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457786/ctrl-c-crashes-python-after-importing-scipy-stats)

Comment: Agreed, I too have tried the above code and it works as expected. You might want to try changing your code (`somecode`) into a loop and testing this without any external dependencies.

Comment: I tried both referenced methods and everything (even my own implementation) works on simple code, but in my actual, which consists of multiple classes and `somecode` uses different methods of these classes, it doesn't work and results in **forrtl: error (200)...**.